# Change path in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to change my jupyter notebook directory using cmd. i am getting following error.['jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp0D9.png).

Comment: Do you have the python scripts folder on your `PATH`?

Comment: yes , this is how i have set it                                                             C:\Users\Sadisha> cd E:\Stat

C:\Users\Sadisha>Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

This error **'Jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.** mostly means the required program is not installed, when system try to find executable binary it can't find so the error is generated. Reinstalling often solve this problem.

**Installation commands using pip**

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

you have to enable server extension to use it, for that

`jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab --sys-prefix`

After this run

```
jupyter lab
```

**Run Jupyter from a specific directory/folder**

(From your attached image)
After you ran `cd  E:\stat` and then ran `Jupyter notebook`
but you can see the path did not changed in next prompt, to change path to `E:\stat` you have to run `E:` after  `cd  E:\stat` and then run `Jupyter notebook`